# How to I pass my file into the top function to split it?

Tags: python

my program is supposed to make a list of the count of each word in a file. I am trying to pass my file into the first function to remove all punctuation.. how can I make my file into a string to do this? Thanks.

```
#def extract_words(string):
    """Returns a list containing each word in the string, ignoring #punctuation, numbers, etc."""
    l = []
    word = ''
    for c in string+' ':
        if c.isalpha():
            word += c
        else:
            if word != '':
                l.append(word.lower())
            word = ''
    return l

#def count_words(filename):
    """Returns a dictionary containing the number of occurrences of each #word in the file."""
    # create a dictionary
    mydict = {}
    # open the file and read the text
    with open(filename, 'r') as myfile:
    # extract each word in the file

    # count the number of times each work occurs.
        for i in myfile.read().split():
            if i in mydict.keys():
                mydict[i] += 1
            else:
                mydict[i] = 1
    # return the dictionary with the word count.
    return mydict
```

Answer (score 0):

if a is the string and you want the output dictionary as b:

```
from collections import Counter
#Make file into a string:
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    a = f.read()
list_word = [i for i in a.replace('\n', '').split() if i.isalpha()]
b = Counter(list_word)
```